# Rollup external paths with iife

Tags: iife, rollupjs

I found next code fragment on the Rollup api page.
If I would be using iife instead of amd.
How would Rollup define this in the bundle?
Or would it expect a preceding <script> tag containing that external code? If the latter would be true: Is there a way to produce a bundle with JS code which dynamically loads JS files through absolute URLs?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try it](https://rollupjs.org/repl?version=0.43.0&shareable=JTdCJTIybW9kdWxlcyUyMiUzQSU1QiU3QiUyMm5hbWUlMjIlM0ElMjJtYWluLmpzJTIyJTJDJTIyY29kZSUyMiUzQSUyMmltcG9ydCUyMCU3QiUyMHNlbGVjdEFsbCUyMCU3RCUyMGZyb20lMjAnZDMnJTNCJTVDbnNlbGVjdEFsbCgncCcpLnN0eWxlKCdjb2xvciclMkMlMjAncHVycGxlJyklM0IlMjIlN0QlNUQlMkMlMjJvcHRpb25zJTIyJTNBJTdCJTIyZm9ybWF0JTIyJTNBJTIyaWlmZSUyMiUyQyUyMm1vZHVsZU5hbWUlMjIlM0ElMjJteUJ1bmRsZSUyMiUyQyUyMmdsb2JhbHMlMjIlM0ElN0IlN0QlMkMlMjJtb2R1bGVJZCUyMiUzQSUyMiUyMiU3RCUyQyUyMmV4YW1wbGUlMjIlM0FudWxsJTdE). You'll see it generates code like this:

```js
(function (d3) {
'use strict';

d3.selectAll('p').style('color', 'purple');

}(d3));
```

In other words yes, it expects there to be a `<script>` tag on the page that defines `d3`.

> Is there a way to produce a bundle with JS code which dynamically loads JS files through absolute URLs?

That's exactly what the `amd` output is. You just need to have an AMD module loader such as require.js or curl.js on the page.

Comment: The thing is we want to use a <script> tag without AMD or RequireJS.

Comment: So put `<script src='https://unpkg.com/whatever'></script>` on your page and use `format: 'iife', globals: { whatever: 'whatever' }`